# Get next date in group in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have data which looks like

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
Date_Construct= c("10/03/2018 00:00", "10/03/2018 00:00","01/01/2016 00:00","21/03/2015 01:25", "21/03/2015 01:25",  "17/04/2016 00:00","17/04/2016 00:00", "20/02/2012 00:00","20/02/2020 00:00")
Date_first_use = c("02/08/2018 00:00","02/08/2018 00:00", "01/04/2016 00:00","NA", "NA", "NA", "NA","13/08/2012 00:00","20/04/2020 00:00")
Date_fail = c("02/08/2019 00:00","02/08/2019 00:00", "21/06/2018 06:42","NA" , "NA" , "17/04/2016 00:00", "17/04/2016 00:00","13/08/2014 07:45","NA")
P_ID = c("0001", "0001" ,"0001" ,"0001", "0001","34000","34000","34000", "00425")
Comp_date= c("16/05/2019 00:00", "10/04/2018 12:55","25/06/2017 00:00","22/04/2015 00:00","08/05/2015 00:00" ,"04/05/2017 00:00" ,"15/07/2016 00:00","01/03/2014 00:00", "20/03/2020 00:00")
Type =  c("a","a","b","c","c","b","b","a","c")
Date_Construct= dmy_hm(Date_Construct)

dfq= data.frame(`P_ID`, `Type`, `Date_Construct`, `Date_first_use`,`Date_fail`, `Comp_date`)%>%
  arrange(P_ID, desc(Date_Construct))%>%
  group_by( P_ID,  Date_Construct, Type)%>%
  mutate(A_ID= cur_group_id())%>%
  select(P_ID,A_ID,Type, Date_Construct, Date_first_use, Date_fail, Comp_date)%>%
  mutate(across(contains("Date", ignore.case = TRUE), dmy_hm))   

View(dfq)
```

It is a data frame of different items (`A_ID`) of type a/b/c, created for different clients (`P_ID`), with date of construction, date of first use and date of failure. Each P_ID may have multiple `A_ID`, and each `A_ID` may have multiple `Comp_date`.

**I need to supply a date for where `Date_fail` is `NA`, which is the `Date_construct` of the next constructed `A_ID` for the same `P_ID`.**

i.e. `Date_fail` for `P_ID` 0001, `A_ID` 1 should be `2016-01-01 00:00:00`.

For `A_ID` which there are no subsequent `A_ID` (as is the case for `P_ID` 00425, `A_ID` 4), the `Date_fail` should remain `NA` .
So result should look like:

```
  P_ID  A_ID Type      Date_Construct      Date_first_use Date_fail            Comp_date                   
1 0001  1      c       2015-03-21 01:25:00  NA             2016-01-01 00:00:00  2015-04-22 00:00:00           
2 0001  1      c       2015-03-21 01:25:00  NA             2016-01-01 00:00:00  2015-05-08 00:00:00           
3 0001  2      b       2016-01-01 00:00:00  2016-04-01     2018-06-21 06:42:00  2017-06-25 00:00:00           
4 0001  3      a       2018-03-10 00:00:00  2018-08-02     2019-08-02 00:00:00  2019-05-16 00:00:00           
5 0001  3      a       2018-03-10 00:00:00  2018-08-02     2019-08-02 00:00:00  2018-04-10 12:55:00         
6 00425 4      c       2020-02-20 00:00:00  2020-04-20     NA                   2020-03-20 00:00:00           
7 34000 5      a       2012-02-20 00:00:00  2012-08-13     2014-08-13 07:45:00  2014-03-01 00:00:00           
8 34000 6      b       2016-04-17 00:00:00  NA             2016-04-17 00:00:00  2017-05-04 00:00:00           
9 34000 6      b       2016-04-17 00:00:00  NA             2016-04-17 00:00:00  2016-07-15 00:00:00
```

I tried this, which I thought worked, but it is just given me the `Date_Construct` of the next row in the group, which isn't correct as some `A_ID` have multiple entries:

```
  arrange(P_ID, Date_Construct)%>%
  group_by(P_ID,) %>%
  mutate(Date_fail2 = sort(Date_Construct, decreasing = FALSE)[row_number(Date_Construct) + 1])%>%
  mutate(Date_fail = if_else( is.na(Date_fail), paste(Date_fail2), paste(Date_fail)))
```

I'm ideally looking for a dplyr solution as I find them easier to understand and reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to `nest` all the variables that can be *different* for the same `A_ID`. (In this case only `Comp_date`)

```r
library(tidyr)

nested = dfq %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(P_ID, A_ID) %>%
  nest(extra = Comp_date)
```

This results in a tibble with one row for each `A_ID`, where the different `Comp_date`s are comfortably nested in their own tibbles:

```
> nested
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   P_ID, Type, Date_Construct [6]
  P_ID   A_ID Type  Date_Construct      Date_first_use      Date_fail           extra           
  <fct> <int> <fct> <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <list>          
1 0001      1 c     2015-03-21 01:25:00 NA                  NA                  <tibble [2 × 1]>
2 0001      2 b     2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-04-01 00:00:00 2018-06-21 06:42:00 <tibble [1 × 1]>
3 0001      3 a     2018-03-10 00:00:00 2018-08-02 00:00:00 2019-08-02 00:00:00 <tibble [2 × 1]>
4 00425     4 c     2020-02-20 00:00:00 2020-04-20 00:00:00 NA                  <tibble [1 × 1]>
5 34000     5 a     2012-02-20 00:00:00 2012-08-13 00:00:00 2014-08-13 07:45:00 <tibble [1 × 1]>
6 34000     6 b     2016-04-17 00:00:00 NA                  2016-04-17 00:00:00 <tibble [2 × 1]>
```

You can now modify this using normal dplyr methods. Your own approach would probably work as well here, but it can be done much more cleanly using `coalesce` and `lead`. Don't forget to `unnest` at the end to get your original structure back:

```r
result = nested %>%
  group_by(P_ID) %>%
  mutate(Date_fail = coalesce(Date_fail, lead(Date_Construct))) %>%
  unnest(extra)
```

Result:

```
> result
# A tibble: 9 x 7
# Groups:   P_ID [3]
  P_ID   A_ID Type  Date_Construct      Date_first_use      Date_fail           Comp_date          
  <fct> <int> <fct> <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 0001      1 c     2015-03-21 01:25:00 NA                  2016-01-01 00:00:00 2015-04-22 00:00:00
2 0001      1 c     2015-03-21 01:25:00 NA                  2016-01-01 00:00:00 2015-05-08 00:00:00
3 0001      2 b     2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-04-01 00:00:00 2018-06-21 06:42:00 2017-06-25 00:00:00
4 0001      3 a     2018-03-10 00:00:00 2018-08-02 00:00:00 2019-08-02 00:00:00 2019-05-16 00:00:00
5 0001      3 a     2018-03-10 00:00:00 2018-08-02 00:00:00 2019-08-02 00:00:00 2018-04-10 12:55:00
6 00425     4 c     2020-02-20 00:00:00 2020-04-20 00:00:00 NA                  2020-03-20 00:00:00
7 34000     5 a     2012-02-20 00:00:00 2012-08-13 00:00:00 2014-08-13 07:45:00 2014-03-01 00:00:00
8 34000     6 b     2016-04-17 00:00:00 NA                  2016-04-17 00:00:00 2017-05-04 00:00:00
9 34000     6 b     2016-04-17 00:00:00 NA                  2016-04-17 00:00:00 2016-07-15 00:00:00
```